# Why a Delphi progressbar increases the execution time of a iteration procedure?

Tags: delphi

Why the use of a progress bar to show the progress of an iteration considerably increases the execution time of the process in question?
Considering the following example:

```
procedure FileToStringList(FileName: String);
var
  fileSource: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  fileSource:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    fileSource.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    for I := 0 to fileSource.Count - 1 do
      begin
       //Code....
      end;
  finally
    fileSource.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you add the update of a progress bar:

```
procedure FileToStringList(FileName: String);
var
  fileSource: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  fileSource:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    fileSource.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    ProgressBar.Properties.Max:= fileSource.Count;
    for I := 0 to fileSource.Count - 1 do
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        ProgressBar.Position:= I;
      end;
  finally
    fileSource.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The time required for the iteration process to be performed is multiplied enormously.

Performing a reading test of a file of 200,000 lines, without the update of the progress bar, the time of the iteration is approximately 8 seconds but, if the update of the progress bar is activated to show the progress of the iteration, this process takes several minutes.

A test with a file of 2,700 lines, the normal time is 2-4 seconds but with the use of a progress bar, the execution time is more than 1 minute.

Can someone indicate if the use of the Application ProcessMessages is incorrect?. The result does not change if the routine is in a unit or on the same form like the progress bar.

Okay I can see the comments but, can someone indicate with an example or link which should be the correct way to update the progress bar in these conditions?

Comment: Yes. Using `Application.ProcessMessages` is bad. But even if it wouldn't and processing one line would take, say 1 ms, human eye wouldn't register that.

Comment: If you have 200,000 lines, you have 200,000 processmessages calls. Even if the progress bar was 1000 pixels wide, you would have 200 updates before it incremented by one pixel, which would be a waste of time.

Comment: I need to show the progress since files with more than one million lines will be read and some sub processes need to be done within the iteration

Comment: The only proper way to do this is to run your work in a background thread communicating its status with the GUI thread in a thread-safe manner (for instance, by sending Windows messages). If that's too much work in this case, you could replace `ProcessMessages` with a progress bar update if more than 200 ms (say) has elapsed since the last progress bar update.

Comment: Also, you *must* put the `try` between the lines `fileSource:= TStringList.Create;` and `fileSource.LoadFromFile(FileName);`. As it is now, memory corruption or AV will ensue if an exception is raised in `TStringList.Create`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I have tested the update of the progress bar and the difference with 27,554 lines is from 5 seconds to 45 seconds, without sub process. And the Try block is there.

Comment: Your problem is the use of `ProcessMessages`. That's expensive. You shouldn't be calling it at all, but I doubt anybody will be able to persuade you to stop. So, have the sense to rate limit the calls. Only update the progress, say at most 10 times a second.

Comment: @Fisad: Yes, I know the `try` block is there. But it introduces a (potentially nasty) bug, since it is used incorrectly. Please read my comment again.

Comment: Your placement of `try` is wrong. Do you want to learn, or are you happy to keep on making this mistake?

Comment: Your edit still gets the try in the wrong place.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: You are right I have corrected the code.

Comment: @Fisad: Still wrong. :( Ive got it right in his/her answer.

Comment: Actually `Application.Processmessages` is not needed to show the change in `Progressbar.Position`.

Comment: This is a third-party progress bar - looks like `TcxProgressBar` - right? If so, make sure to mention that in your question. As these might have different behavior than the VCL controls.

Comment: Just tested, if you are using `TcxProgressBar` I can understand why you have been calling `Application ProcessMessages`, as I do not see any progress without. You need to call `Update` explicitly, but make sure to limit the calls like others suggested.

Comment: Yes, use the `Update()` method of the ProgressBar, or even of the Form itself. Do not use `ProcessMessages`. And don't update the UI on every loop iteration, do it on every X iterations instead.

Comment: One way to reduce the impact of the progress display is reduce the number of times you update it, e.g. update it only every 100th or 1000th time. Alternatively check how long ago the last update was and update only every 0.5 seconds. For simple processing this is probably fine. Putting code in a background thread may create debugging nightmares, if you do not have any experience with multi threading.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your application only transforms the input file, then there is no need for a special thread and you can use following code.

In the case that an application allows the user to perform another operations while processing the file, then a background thread should be used.

```
procedure FileToStringList(FileName: String);
var
   fileSource: TStringList;
   I,J: Integer;
begin
  fileSource:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    fileSource.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    ProgressBar.Properties.Max:= fileSource.Count;
    J:=10;//TODO make it better
    for I := 0 to fileSource.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if (I mod J = 0) then
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        ProgressBar.Position:= I;
      end;
    end;
    ProgressBar.Position:= fileSource.Count;
  finally
    fileSource.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or you can call your processMessages on time:

```
procedure FileToStringList(FileName: String);
var
   fileSource: TStringList;
   I,J: Integer;
   lastCheck: TDateTime;
begin
  fileSource:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    fileSource.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    ProgressBar.Properties.Max:= fileSource.Count;
    J:=1000;//refresh in ms
    lastCheck:=now;
    for I := 0 to fileSource.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if (lastCheck+j)<now then
      begin
        lastCheck:=now;
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        ProgressBar.Position:= I;
      end;
    end;
    ProgressBar.Position:= fileSource.Count;
  finally
    fileSource.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Walking around. The real solution is doing such stuff in a worker thread, not eliminating consequences. Do not call `Application.ProcessMessages` ever is a good advice, IMHO.

Comment: @Ive: I've used J: = 1000 and it's a bit better but, because of what I've been investigating now, the thread solution would be the correct one.

Comment: Yes Worker Thread is correct one,  but this is the simple one :)

Comment: using Application.ProcesMessages in a case like this is a very bad technique.

Answer (score 1):

You're not really "just adding a progress bar". Your use of `Application.ProcessMessages;` messages means that you're also pumping all manner of additional messages doing other work. So now your "busy/main work" is competing for CPU time on the same thread (and CPU) as all the other messages going through your application. We're certainly in no position to comment on what other messages might be flowing though your application.

Busy work should not be done in the main thread. And it's generally fairly easy to wrap a method into a thread provided it isn't already too tightly coupled to your GUI.

*No doubt you've been told all this in comments already.*

---

First take note of a few important rules:

- don't interact with your GUI from your child threads (Synchronise or Queue calls to code that updates GUI);
- avoid sharing data<sup>1</sup> between threads (including main thread);
- if you must share data ensure your threads co-ordinate<sup>1</sup> their access to avoid race conditions (too big a topic to go into detail).

Then the following is the minimum needed:

1. Define your thread.
2. Implement your main processing in the `Execute()` method.
3. Create and start your thread.
4. Since you want to update a progress bar, and remembering "Rules to note": make sure you Queue those updates.

But there are a number of more advanced considerations you can apply to improving your thread. (Those will be left to you for further research.)

5. You would also be well advised to also take advice [Ive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49068862/224704) and others have already given and reduce the number of times you update your progress. Excessive updates just wastes time; especially with cross-thread operations (see last section).
6. How do you interrupt your thread if your user wants to cancel the job or close the app?
7. How do you manage the possibility of your user starting too many jobs?
8. How do you deal with errors in your threads?
9. How do you want to manage what happens when your thread terminates.

---

The following sample code is a trimmed down version of what you need in 1-4. You can fill in the trivial bits I left out.

1)

```
type
  TFileProcessor = class(TThread)
  public
    constructor Create(const AFileName: string);
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;
```

2 & 4)

Note that you could pass the progress bar instance in your constructor and update it from your thread. But even though it's a little more work, it's much cleaner to define a callback event on your thread, and allow your GUI to handle the event in order to choose exactly what it wishes to do.

```
procedure TFileProcessor.Execute;
var
  fileSource: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  fileSource:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    fileSource.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    { GUI interaction must be queued.
      ProgressBar.Properties.Max:= fileSource.Count;}
      FPosition := 0;
      FCount := fileSource.Count;
      Queue(DoUpdateProgress);
    for I := 0 to fileSource.Count - 1 do
      begin
        { Obviously this must go!
          Application.ProcessMessages;}
        { Again GUI interaction must be Queued
          ProgressBar.Position:= I;}
        FPosition := I;
        Queue(DoUpdateProgress); {TIP: Reduce your progress updates for 
                                  more performance improvement; updating 
                                  on every single line is overkill.}
      end;
  finally
    fileSource.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFileProcessor.DoUpdateProgress();
begin
  if Assigned(FOnUpdateProgress) then
    FOnUpdateProgress(FPosition, FCount);
end;
```

3)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(...);
var
  LThread: TFileProcessor;
begin
  LThread := TFileProcessor.Create(FFileName);
  LThread.OnUpdateProgress := HandleUpdateProgress;
  LThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  LThread.Start;
end;
```

4)

As mentioned earlier it's cleaner if your form controls what GUI controls it wants to update and how in response to progress updates. E.g. You could update a label at the same same time if desired without any change to the thread and job code.

```
procedure TForm1.HandleUpdateProgress(APosition, ACount: Integer);
begin
  ProgressBar.Position := APosition;
  ProgressBar.Properties.Max := ACount;
  Label1.Caption := Format('Line %d of %d', [APosition, ACount]);
end;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I'd like to emphasise the point that you should avoid sharing data with multi-threaded code. Cross-thread operations are much more expensive than same-thread operations. (*This includes notifications to the main thread.*)

For example, on my system, the thread code above has the following overheads.

- 200,000 Queued events to the main thread has an overhead of almost 1 second.
- Depending on what you do inside `HandleUpdateProgress` you might find it takes some time processing all the queued messages for a while after your file has actually finished processing. (On my system updating a standard label and progress bar, this takes 5 seconds.)